# Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in /PATH/initClass.php on line 5

Tags: php, html

I am getting the following error!

> Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in >/PATH/initClass.php on line 5

For the code:

```
<?php
Class init
{
    public const THEME = "aman/dev/frontend/";
    private $root = dirname(__dir__)."/aman/dev/fontend/";
    public function getFile($name,$value)
    {
        list(
            $title
            ) = $value;


    }
}
?>
```

I can't seem to figure out what's is happening.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe your issue is the use of "`__dir__`" in the expression for a private variable. I haven't dived deep into this, but I expect that since it can't know `__dir__` until runtime, that it doesn't want to use it that way. Try setting the private variable to null, then set it with the full expression in a constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using a function operation to set a value to a class variable. To fix your problem, use the following code (i.e. move initialization to the constructor)

```
<?php
Class init
{
    public const THEME = "aman/dev/frontend/";
    private $root;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->root =  dirname(__dir__)."/aman/dev/fontend/";
    }

    public function getFile($name,$value)
    {
        list(
            $title
            ) = $value;


    }
}
?>
```